# Zend 2.2 How to validate a simple email input using inputfilter?

Tags: zend-framework

How do i validate simple email input in Zend 2.2. I had a look at the set of methods in the documentation but nothing directly related to Emails, do i have to use regular expressions ?

[http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/2.1/namespaces/Zend.Filter.html][1]

in my class Contact implements InputFilterAwareInterface there is function called

```
public function getInputFilter(){

 $inputFilter->add(array(
                'email'     => 'email',
                'required' => true,
                'filters'  => array(
                    array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                    array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
                ),
            ));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way to do this, it has to be validator rather than a filter

working code is given below

```
$inputFilter->add(array(
                'name'     => 'email',
                'required' => true,
                'filters'  => array(
                    array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                    array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
                ),
                'validators' => array(
                    array(
                       'name' => 'EmailAddress'
                    ),
                ),
            ));
```